# Android ListView is inflated twice

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm very new to Android, and I have a problem that I don't know where to start looking for its cause.

I have a Fragment with a `ListView` that is populated with a Loader.
When I launch the app the `ListView` is shown twice, one on top of the other, here is a screenshot of how  it looks like:

[image: Duplicated list view]

I have no idea where to start looking for why this happens, but I guess I'll have to give some code so here is my Fragment code:

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int FORECAST_LOADER = 0;
    // For the forecast view we're showing only a small subset of the stored data.
    // Specify the columns we need.
    private static final String[] FORECAST_COLUMNS = {
            // In this case the id needs to be fully qualified with a table name, since
            // the content provider joins the location & weather tables in the background
            // (both have an _id column)
            // On the one hand, that's annoying.  On the other, you can search the weather table
            // using the location set by the user, which is only in the Location table.
            // So the convenience is worth it.
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + WeatherContract.WeatherEntry._ID,
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE,
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_DESC,
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MAX_TEMP,
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_MIN_TEMP,
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_SETTING,
            WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_WEATHER_ID,
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LAT,
            WeatherContract.LocationEntry.COLUMN_COORD_LONG
    };

    // These indices are tied to FORECAST_COLUMNS.  If FORECAST_COLUMNS changes, these
    // must change.
    static final int COL_WEATHER_ID = 0;
    static final int COL_WEATHER_DATE = 1;
    static final int COL_WEATHER_DESC = 2;
    static final int COL_WEATHER_MAX_TEMP = 3;
    static final int COL_WEATHER_MIN_TEMP = 4;
    static final int COL_LOCATION_SETTING = 5;
    static final int COL_WEATHER_CONDITION_ID = 6;
    static final int COL_COORD_LAT = 7;
    static final int COL_COORD_LONG = 8;

    private ForecastAdapter mForecastAdapter;

    public ForecastFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // The CursorAdapter will take data from our cursor and populate the ListView.
        mForecastAdapter = new ForecastAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // CursorAdapter returns a cursor at the correct position for getItem(), or null
                // if it cannot seek to that position
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if (cursor != null) {
                    String locationSetting = Utility.getPreferredLocation(getActivity());
                    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)
                            .setData(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocationWithDate(
                                    locationSetting, cursor.getLong(COL_WEATHER_DATE)
                            ));
                    startActivity(detailIntent);
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(FORECAST_LOADER, null, this);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void updateWeather(){
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask(getActivity());
        String location = Utility.getPreferredLocation(getActivity());
        weatherTask.execute(location);
    }

    void onLocationChanged() {
        updateWeather();
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(FORECAST_LOADER, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String location = Utility.getPreferredLocation(getActivity());

        //Sort order: Ascending by date
        String sortOrder = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_DATE + " ASC";
        Uri weatherForLocation = WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.buildWeatherLocationWithStartDate(
                location, System.currentTimeMillis());

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                weatherForLocation,
                FORECAST_COLUMNS,
                null,
                null,
                sortOrder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        if (!data.moveToFirst())
            updateWeather();
        mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        mForecastAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have the Fragment declared in your Activity's layout and adding it, at the same time, with a transaction ?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but can you please tell me what do you mean ? I have this line `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);` in the `onCreateView` method of the fragment and in the  `content_main.xml` file this: `<fragment ...
    android:name="com.udacity.frliran.sunshine.ForecastFragment"
    ...
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />` is that what you mean ?

Comment: could you post your Activity's onCreate, and its layout ?

Comment: the comment is limited in char length so I can't post all of the `onCreate` but the only part seems relevant to me is this `if (savedInstanceState == null){
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment, new ForecastFragment(), FORECASTFRAGMENT_TAG)
                    .commit();
        }` does it say something or sould I post all code ?

Comment: I did add an answer. Have a look to it. Don't use comments to past code. You have always the possibility to edit your question

Comment: Yes, you are right. It fixed it :-) Thank you very much, I marked your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I am seeing in the screenshot, it looks like you added the same fragment twice, to the current view's hierarchy. The most common mistake is to declare the Fragment in the `Activity`'s layout, using the `<fragment` tag, and programmatically using a specific transaction, which, of course, results in having the same fragment twice at screen. To fix it, replace the `<fragment` in your layout with a `<FrameLayout` and add the fragment programmatically. E.g.

```
<FrameLayout 
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and in your Activity's onCreate

```
if (savedInstanceState == null){ 
    getSupportFragmentManager() .beginTransaction() .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment(), FORECASTFRAGMENT_TAG) .commit(); 
}
```

Comment: One question please, I removed this `tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"` from the xml layout file but it didn't help, only when I remove this `getSupportFragmentManager() .beginTransaction() .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment(), FORECASTFRAGMENT_TAG) .commit();` it helps, and I want to have to fragment inflated like this `getSupportFragmentManager() .beginTransaction() .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment(), FORECASTFRAGMENT_TAG) .commit();` and not in the xml. So how do I do this ?

Comment: you have to remove the whole `<fragment` tag from the xml and not only `tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"`.

Comment: This is the content of the "content_main.xml" file: `<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.udacity.frliran.sunshine.ForecastFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />` If I remove it all it gives an error because the file is empty...

Comment: replace it with the `FrameLayout`. That's all.

Comment: Wohooo, now it works :-) Thank you very much again :-)

Comment: are you still using R.id.fragment in your activity ?

Comment: Yes, but I replaced the `<fragment>` tag from the xml file with `<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />`

Comment: Yes, it works now and I finally understood the concept

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you are declaring via XML the fragment, and then **inflating it again**.

You should either use a better approach and instead of putting the fragment in the XML, add an empty framelayout and add / replace the fragment each time  (take a look at [this](https://github.com/tryadelion/EricUtils/blob/master/EricUtils/ericutils2/src/main/java/com/software/cpteric/ericutils/FragmentUtils.java) method i have in my custom library ) , this way it will show only once,
 or not inflate it again ( but onResume could also duplicate it, and provides no freedom of changing the fragment being shown).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is also correct